# Rewriting API from .Net Framework to .netcore ,Getting 'System.NotSupportedException' in attempt to get file stream

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, filestream

I am Migrating one of projects to .NET CORE MVC ,

1. Previous code had API to Upload document, re-written same
2. Rewritten Above Code to below code , used "using
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim" to get HttpRequestMessage

[Older Code: Working Fine in .NET FRAMEWORK]

```
public HttpResponseMessage UploadFile(string filetype)//old code
    {
        Stream file = Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
        string id;
        id = DocumentHelper.SaveDocument(filetype, file);

        return Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.OK, id);
    }


public  HttpResponseMessage UploadFile(string filetype)//Re-Written Code
    {
        HttpRequestMessageFeature requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageFeature(Request.HttpContext);
        HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = requestMessage.HttpRequestMessage;
        Stream file = httpRequestMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
        string id;
        id = DocumentHelper.SaveDocument(filetype, file);

        return httpRequestMessage.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.OK, id);
    }
```

[Quickwatch for ReWritten Code when trying to read content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRXDd.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc4AF.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRXDd.png)

Tried using Request.Body with stream reader, and enabled buffering.

Any Pointers How to read the stream from Microsoft.AspNetCore.HTTP.HttpRequest,I AM TRYING TO AVOID async function that would force me to change return type

Comment: The error about `NotSupportedException`  seems something not support, like  `Encoding Type `. As we can't reproduce the issue in our side from your code, so could you share us your code about this code, and pls hide your sensitive info.   If we can test in our side, we can help u.

Comment: Yes @Jason I checked issue lies with encoding because in Content-Type I am getting null even though Content-Length is there (Fyi I  am trying to upload a file via API)
i tried it with Postman,its working,Content type comes as multipart/form-data,
but not when i tried to upload from my application.
also I am using httpclient to make POST calls,  Request.Form seems to be coming null as well ,
trying to set Content-Type as Multipart/Form-data